# Windows Share Remapping

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, network-share

I have a small network and users normally access network shares like

\\office-server\soft\

\\office-server\public\

\\office-server\dev\

it is some how possible, that users just type

\\software\ and somehow request goes to \\office-server\soft\

\\myDrive\ and request goes to \\office-server\public\

I don't want to map network drives on users' PC,

I have looked in to DNS but i think in DNS this is not possible.(correct me if i am wrong)

i can not think of any other way at the moment.

Any advise

Thanks 
ALi

Comment: I ran across this recently and thought of it immediately when I read your post. Hopefully it will be of some help. https://superuser.com/questions/528836/map-network-drive-and-provide-an-alias

Comment: When you use UNC paths, the problem is that your first part is the server name or IP address, and then the share name after that. So even if you create CNAME records on your DNS for `software`, `myDrive` and such, you'll still need to fill in the the share name portion of the UNC path. So you'll get `\\software\software`. Is there a reason why you don't want to map the drives for the user's PC?

Comment: to be really honest there is no good reason, i can work with mapped drives, but i was thinking is that even possible, and apparently it is not possible.